# How to select multiple elements by id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio buttons:

```
<p>
    <label for="input_1">Path to Excellent </label> 
    <input id="input_1" name="radio" type="radio" value="1" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="input_2">Award of Excellence</label> 
    <input id="input_2" name="radio" type="radio" value="2" />
</p>
```

I would like to get val() from one of them using their ids: "input_1" or "input_2" by jQuery, something like this:

```
$('input[#input_1,#input_2]:checked').val();
```

My aim is to get val() from one of them that is checked, by id. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the [starts](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) of the `id` in this case:

```
$("input[id^='input_']:checked").val();
```